# How to access type's index in the template type parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I would like to access type's index when expanding a type parameter pack into an `std::tuple<...>`.

For example, given a type pack of `<int, double, float>` I would like to build an `std::tuple<...>` that looks as follows:

```
std::tuple<std::array<int,0>, std::array<double,1>, std::array<float, 2>>
//                     ^  ^                ^    ^                ^    ^
//                     T  I                T    I                T    I
```

Here is an implementation that does almost exactly what I want, but it works only for type packs of size 3 (see the comment next to the hack). How do I fix this to work independently of `TT...`s size?

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... TT>
struct Foo {
    template <std::size_t... Indices>
    struct Baz {
       std::tuple<std::array<TT,Indices>...> baz;
    };
    Baz<0,1,2> bar; // <<<=== Here is the hack: I make a fixed-size pack; I want it to match TT...
};

int main() {
    Foo<int,double,float> foo;
    std::cout << std::get<0>(foo.bar.baz).size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<1>(foo.bar.baz).size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::get<2>(foo.bar.baz).size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo.](https://ideone.com/fKuQYC)

Comment: I am just curious. I have seen similar requests in the past and I am asking myself if these are just examples for more relevant code, puzzles somebody is interested to solve or if there is a real usage for such a data structure.

Comment: @2b-t This is not a real data structure I am using. I picked `std::array` because it has a numeric template parameter and a type template parameter, so I don't need to show my own template type in the example.

Comment: Oh, this actually makes sense! Thanks a lot for explaining. Definitely one of the most interesting variadic-template-related questions I came across recently: I actually didn't know you could actually do `std::array<T,I>...` with two parameter packs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track of nesting to have two packs. What you need now is a [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) that lets you create the desired pack instead of hardcoding it via `Baz<0,1,2> bar;`.

The basic idea is to define a function template that takes a `std::integer_sequence<size_t,I...>` parametrized on a pack and call that with a `std::make_integer_sequence<size_t,N>` so the pack `I...` can be deduced from a single number `N`, then it is just folding:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename...Ts>
struct foo {
    static const size_t N = sizeof...(Ts);
    template <size_t ... I>
    static auto helper(std::integer_sequence<size_t,I...>){
        return std::tuple<std::array<Ts,I>...>{};
    }
    using type = decltype(helper(std::make_integer_sequence<size_t,N>{}));
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::is_same< std::tuple<std::array<int,0>, std::array<double,1>, std::array<float, 2>>,
                 foo<int,double,float>::type >::value;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5c78Wxo1)

Comment: Very interesting... I actually didn't know you could  do something like `std::array<Ts,I>...`! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @2b-t: OP already used `std::array<Ts, Indices>...` BTW.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I only noticed that later on. I have seen you have answered similar questions with e.g. a `std::tuple` instead of a `std::array`. I see I have still a lot to learn from you folks. :) Have you got any idea what somebody would use such a complex data structure for? I have seen quite a few similar questions so it seems to be less exotic than I initially thought.

Comment: @2b-t yes, you should thank OP ;). If they didnt use the parallel packs, I wasn't able to come up with this answer. I don't know what exactly OP has in their real code, I'm also curious, but it didnt matter to answer the question because their example was mcve enough to add the missing part. I doubt they actually want an array of size 0

Comment: @2b-t I try to write answers to stand for themselves. If it was a personal letter to the op, then probably instead of "You are on the right track of nesting to have two packs..." i would have written "Wow, this is really cool, let me see if I can fiddle around with code until i get it to work somehow by trial and error" :P